# How to Lengthen the Username Field on Django User Model?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django web application that is deployed on Heroku. I'm using Django's user model for authentication. My goal is to lengthen the `username` field from 30 characters to 100 characters.

I overrode the default `User` model with my own `AbstractUser` model:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 100 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
```

I want to update the max_length of the `username` field from 30 to 100. I can do this locally without any issue by simply updating the line `max_length=30` to `max_length=100`, running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

However, the migration file is created in my virtual environment `(venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\migrations)` folder so I'm not sure where to deploy it to Heroku. I have my entire venv folder excluded through my `.gitignore` file. I do not have a venv folder on Heroku.

Where/how should I deploy and apply the migration file to Heroku?

Comment: Aren't your migrations created in `<project_name>/<app_name>/migrations` ?

Comment: Typically, yes when I make changes to the models that I defined. But since this is the Django "auth" class, an "auth/migrations" folder doesn't exist on Heroku. Any suggestions on how to apply this?

Comment: A custom user model is the way to go. Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Thanks @bimsapi! I've implemented a custom user model as described in the docs but now I need to update the username field on the underlying user model to make it longer. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Simply over-ride the username field, setting the required length, not null, uniqueness, etc. When you create and run your migration, remember that `auth_user` won't be relevant any more. You should have `yourapp_user`. If you have data, you'll need migrations to move the data around - create new table, copy user records, update all foreign key fields, etc.